# Problem get jwt with Spring boot to angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, cookies, jwt

I have a problem with a POST request from Angular to Spring. Here is my error in the console.

[image: Error in console]

Back-end, I have correctly entered my parameters for the CORS

```java
 protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",request.getHeader("origin"));
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromCookie(request);
            if (agentProxy.authSuccess(jwt)){
                filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            } else {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
```

and when I get to the recovery of the JWT

```
String jwt = getJwtFromCookie(request);
```

He gets nothing back.
My forehead with my method:

```
createNoteRessource(noteRessource: NoteRessourceModel, idRessource: number){
    const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    const httpOption = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-type':'application/json'}),
      withCredentials:true
    };

    return this.http.post(
      this.baseUrl+'/noteRessource/create/'+idRessource, noteRessource, httpOption).pipe(
        tap(_=> this.log("Ajout d'une note ressource")),
      catchError(this.handleError<NoteRessourceModel>("createNoteRessource"))
    );
```

No matter how much I turned the problem around and nothing, I've been looking for 2 days.

I don't really understand the problem. My url is correct ...
I have a doubt when I see the header of my POST request on the client side.
[image: Error]

Frankly I do not see ...
Back side I get no Cookie even though I have some

```
    private String getJwtFromCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if(cookies==null)
            return "";
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("AuthToken")) {
                String accessToken = cookie.getValue();
                if (accessToken == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                return accessToken;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If someone has an idea ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough if you just add a `@CrossOrigin("http://yourAngularUrl:port")` annotation above your controller class declaration.
So if you are developing on your local machine, and using default angular port the annotation will look like this

```java
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class HelloCOntroller{}
```